# Creating a Bibliography instead of a Reference section

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sharelatex

Working on my thesis I found the need to create a bibliography and so I tryed to use biblatex. I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-N2qtTnP1sg but I can only get a "Reference" section instead of a "Bibliography" one. Could someone help me creating a proper "Bibliography" section? Also, is it possible to create the bibliography whitout making citation in the text? 
I link a sharelatex document with just a simple section, a table of contents and the "Reference" section: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/593597786d2ad77f1463f105

Thank you very much for your time and help,

Edoardo S.

Comment: Try with `\nocite{*}`

Comment: And `\printbibliography[title={Bibliography}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{litteratur.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Bibliography}]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: You could add that a heading like 'references' is standard for `article`-like document classes, `book`- and `report`-like classes use 'bibliography'. You could write `\printbibliography[title={\bibname}]` to make use of `biblatex`'s translation features.

Comment: @moewe Yes, this seem the origin of the problem: A reference "section" in a thesis? But often people have their own thoughts of how made things, (and without mention so many odd thesis templates) and the question was not about what document class one should use to write a thesis.